# Templating language, determine current scope

Tags: javascript, regex, scope, templating

I'm working with a tempting language that supports changing scope using special delimiters, like this:

```
%% scope Foo %%
Stuff
%% end %%
```

Blocks can be nested indefinitely like so:

```
%% scope Foo %%
Stuff in the Foo namespace
  %% scope Bar %%
     Stuff in the bar namespace
  %% end %%
%% end %%
```

When editing one of these templates in a textarea, I'd like a Javascript function to run to report out the current scope. The current line number and cursor position are known already and can be passed to the function.

In other words, using the example above, if my cursor is anywhere on the second line, the function should log 'Foo'. Likewise, if I'm on the 4th line, it should log 'Bar'. If I'm at the very beginning of the third line, (before the %%), it should log "Foo".

Comment: How do we get the cursor position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
value = "%% scope Foo %% \nStuff in the Foo namespace\n  %% scope Bar %% \n     Stuff in the bar namespace \n  %% end %% \n%% end %%" // the value of the text area
cursor= Math.round(Math.random() * value.length) //just to get a random cursor position for testing

console.log(logTag(cursor,value), cursor); // should be foo or bar

function logTag (pos,string) {
    string = string.slice(0,pos);
    string = string.match(/%%\s*scope\s*(\w*)\s*%%/g);
    string = string[string.length - 1].match(/%%\s*scope\s*(\w*)\s*%%/)[1];
    return string;
}
```

This function simply gets all the `%% scope <something> %%` and returns the latest  which would be the scope in which the user is typing in. The spaces can be ignored. And  can only contain alphanumeric and underscore.

Comment: You can also use `+` instead of `*`. `+` is for chars to be repeated one or more than one time, `*` is for 0 or more than 1 time. Let me know if it worked.